# Setting a JSON Object from an input field

Tags: json

I basically have the following flow:

XML -> JSON -> Spring MVC -> jsp page, which is displayed as a table with editable fields.

How do make is so that when i edit a field value it correct updates the Json Object?

I have used some nasty hacking at the moment, as i know (testing) the values/object I am going to get, so im just parsing the JSON string in javascript and sending that back.

So i can then just convert the json object (with new values) and post it back.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the serialize method from prototypejs.

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/form/serialize

just by calling .serialize() you'll be able to get the updated object.